# Save custom objects as struct in matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, struct, save

Data tends to survive longer than code. So I want to save my objects as struct.

The idea is to overwrite the `saveobj` method calling `struct` recursively on itself.

```
classdef foo < handle
    properties
        Data = 12
    end

    methods
        function data = saveobj(o)
            data = struct(o);
        end
    end
end
```

I now call:

```
>> bar = foo;
>> save('test', 'bar')
>> bar2 = load('test')
>> class(bar2.bar)
 'foo'
```

However the saved object is still of type `foo`. Any help figuring out where I screwed up would be appreciated. Thanks

In case it matters I'm using R2012a on RHLE6

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that despite the documentation implying that the output from `saveobj` gets saved with no knowledge that it originated from an object, that is not the case.  The structure knows that it came from an object, and when loaded will get passed to a `loadobj` method if it exists, or the constructor if it doesn't.

One way to overcome this is to overload `save`, and then call `save` on the struct within the `save` method of the object; another is to have a method that returns a struct and then call `save` on that struct.  There are probably also some hacks that can be done to make it a little more automatic, which is most likely what you really want.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Yes, your right I misinterpret the manual. I worked out an ugly solution using also `loadobj`. In case you have time I would value your input on it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a truly ugly hack-around, which might help somebody. Due to its ugliness I will however still wait for an answer.

As Phil already pointed out is the class name still stored with the file. However we can trick `matlab` with an other file with the same name.

My original class looks like this:

```
classdef foo < handle
    %// This is the original class used to some stuff and it holds
    %// important data. But I lost it over time...
    properties
       Data = 12
    end

    methods
        function data = saveobj(o)
            for f = properties(o)'
                data.(f{1}) = saveobj(o.(f{1}));
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now, since I assume I don't have the original source anymore I can use a dummy class to load the data.

```
classdef foo < handle
    %// This is the pretender class source. Since I lost the source of 
    %// the original class.
    methods (Static)
        function data = loadobj(data)
            global DATA

            DATA = data;
        end
    end
end
```

The load will naturally fail, but I can extract the struct feed into the `loadobj` method by calling:

```
global DATA
```

As I said a very ugly solution. That's why I'll wait till somebody smart comes around and finds a better way to solve this problem, but I thought I post it in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Another hack-around might be to save the class-code while saving the object.

For loading the object of your class, you could first load the code, store it as a m-file and then load the object of the class.